# Text subsetting between vectors in R

Tags: r, arrays, subset, multiple-columns

I have two vectors with given names as follows in `R`:

```
A <- data.frame(c("Nick", "Maria", "Liam", "Oliver", "Sophia", "james", "Lucas Theo"))
B  <- data.frame(c("Liam", "Theo", "Evelyn Elsa", "James", "Harper", "Amelia"))
```

I want to compare the two vectors and create a vector `C` with the names of vector `B` that are not in the vector `A`. I want the code to ignore the capital letters, i.e. to recognise that `James` and `james` is the same and also if a name appear as part of a double name, i.e., `Theo`, to also recognise it as different.
In the end, the result must be

```
C <- data.frame(c("Theo", "Evelyn Elsa", "Harper","Amelia"))
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may convert the vectors extract to a common case (`upper`), use `%in%` to find the elements that are present in A from B, negate (`!`) and subset the B based on that logical  vector

```
C <- data.frame(col1 = B[[1]][!toupper(B[[1]]) %in% toupper(A[[1]])])
```

-output

```
C
         col1
1        Theo
2 Evelyn Elsa
3      Harper
4      Amelia
```